# Service или asynctask

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Нужен совет. У меня в приложении регулярно нужно получать данные с сервера. И я думаю как это сделать более рационально по ресурсам и по производительности. Сейчас используется вариант, я получаю асинктаском данные с сервера загоняю их в `hashMap` и с ними потом работаю. Второй способ: создать сервис который будет с сервера загонять данные в базу `sqlite`, а потом уже с этой базой работать. Какой способ более правильный по ресурсам, быстродействию?(если надо приведу исходники)

Подробнее теперь. В базе на сервере будет где-то сотни записей, по 20 атрибутов каждая запись. и каждые секунд 10 нужно будет делать такой запрос на получение всех полей и всех атрибутов  в виде `json` массива (почти все эти значения могут изменяться, поэтому приходится постоянно подгружать все). Потом этот массив я перевожу в удобный для меня `HashMap` и пользуюсь им как мне угодно. Я так подумал: сервис скорее всего толще чем асинктаск, да и обращение к базе будет медленнее чем напрямую к `hashMap`, поэтому наверно пока оставлю асинктаски.
хотя я видел довольно похожее приложение как у меня и там было реализовано сервисом. Маркеры на карте появлялись постепенно, при этом карта была активна. При асинктаске, нужно ждать пока выполнится задание. Но я не думаю, что это плюс. Например, если зайти в то приложение, то карта пустая и глупый юзер может не дождаться и просто выключить, а к асинктаску можно присобачить прогрес диалог и юзер будет ждать пока выполнится задача.(можно конечно присобачить и к сервису прогресс дайлог но это уже извращение)

Comment: чем проще, тем лучше. когда асинктаска вам будет не хватать по постановке задачи переводите в сервис, когда памяти не будет хватать или нужна будет вся история с последнего запуска пишите в базу. Ресурсы и быстродействие надо считать, когда задача решена. Конечно, чем меньше сущностей требуется для выполнения задачи, тем лучше, будет выше и быстродействие и ресурсов меньше.  
ЗЫ слишком общий вопрос, слишком общий ответ.

Comment: я написал немного подробнее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Асинк таски уже использовать не рекомендуется. В крупных банковских приложениях от низ уже ушли. Технология Сервис + Контент провайдер много лучше. Прогресс бар - что мешает прикрутить его к сервису?? У вас должен быть `ServiceHelper` шлющий коллбэки, по ним и стоит обновлять прогресс бар.

[Вот официальная спецификация Google для реализации RestAPI при помощи сервисов](https://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-developing-RESTful-android-apps.pdf)

По быстродействию и ресурсам, даже если вы что то и потеряете, то выиграете в надежности приложения. Потому что даже при критической ошибке сервиса, ваше приложение останется работать.

По материалам:

1. Реализация колбэков и прогресс бара, а также самой модели Service + ContentProvider + Activity - [Организация архитектуры взаимодействия Activity и Service](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144275/)
2. Еще один пример на эту тему - [Написание простого приложения для работы с RESTful API под Android](http://habrahabr.ru/post/176729/)

От себя совет, переводите ваши апы на `Service + ContentProvider + Activity` за этим будущее. На Google IO был доклад на эту тему: [Developing Android REST client applications](www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html). Кстати там использовалась похожая структура.

P.S. Как то проходил собеседование в один крупный банк как Android разработчик, так там как услышали про возможность AsyncTask, чуть не закидали яйцами за само предложение :) :)

Comment: наконец-то кто-то дал профессиональный совет. за колбэки отедельно спасибо, а то я не знал как реализовывать колбэки. Понятно что без них невозможно обеспечить нормальную безопасную работу сервисов.

Comment: Спасибо за оценку ) Удачи в реализации. У меня разобраться с ними  - занял один вечер. У вас думаю не больше займет :) Ничего страшного в них нет ))

Comment: например у меня оператор лайф, который предоставляет ужасный интернет и заранее неизвестно как он себя поведет, конечно же если использовать в данному случае асинктаск, то есть вероятность вылета всего приложения - это неприемлимо. А даже если с сервисом что-то произойдет это не страшно.

Comment: Тем более сервис всегда можно перезапустить :)

Comment: афигенные вы пишите программы, которые падают от отсутствия интернета. учитесь перехватывать исключения. дело не в асинктаске, а в кривых руках. сервис тут не поможет. у вас таким макаром и главное приложение упадет, обратившись к упавшему сервису.

Comment: Я всего лишь отписал свое видение (и не только свое) реализации REST API + Android. То что исключения нужно перехватывать и обрабатывать это понятно :) Но есть много подводных камней и не только uncaughtException и не только системное завершение Androidom для освобождения ресурсов. Вообще можно долго разглагольствовать на тему что нужно сохранять состояние приложение и.т.д.  Но автор задал другой вопрос и конкретный. А осуждать (или мнить себя самым крутым разрабом) может каждый :) Удачи Вам!

Comment: мой комментарий к вашему комментарию. что дескать сервис упадет и ладно, заново запустим. вы, похоже, это считаете фичей, а не багом. т.е. написать красивый рест для вас важнее правильной, безотказной работы программы. при чем тут крутость? да еще мнить. речь вообще не об асинктаске и не о сервисах. отсутствие интернета (или другой необработанный случай) - падение программы и не важно что у нее внутри. вот что главное. а за ваш ответ я бы плюс поставил (и собирался, зайдя сюда), если б не эти комментарии.  
Удачи и вам.

Comment: Вы извините если задел вас :) Что то вечер не задался....

Comment: у меня иногда когда сижу с мобильного вылетает socket timeout exception, то есть интернет вроде бы есть и девайс тоже так думает, но почему-то его нет, либо это такая большая задержка. не знаю в чем дело. в любом случае обработаю тайм аут exception